# List bbPress Forums Function

Tags: bbpress

Looking for a simple bbPress function that will list all forums to iterate through with `foreach()`. `bbp_list_forums()` seems to only work for subforums.

Answer (score 1):

My thinking was wrong about this-- you'll need to add a loop, similar to working with Wordpress itself. Here's the code that worked for me to create an array of forums keyed on their respective ID:

```
$forum_names = array();

if ( bbp_has_forums() ) {
    while ( bbp_forums() ) {

        bbp_the_forum();

        $forum_id = bbp_get_forum_id();

        $forum_names[$forum_id] = bbp_get_forum_title();

    } // while()
} // if()
```

It looks like you could work with the functions in `bbpress/includes/forums/template.php` to do this another way as well.